# Ubuntu in suspend mode shuts off when room is cold

Tags: 15.04, suspend, temperature

I am suspending Ubuntu every day so I can faster load it the next time.

However, in the past few days temperature goes below 5°C over the night, and in the morning I notice that the PC is shut down, instead of being suspended. So I have to boot it instead to wake it from the suspend mode.

This does not happen if I suspend the PC during the day as the room temperature is higher (around 20°C).

Is there a way to solve this strange issue?

Comment: This seem like hardware problem instead of software!

Comment: @BeGood Can you narrow it down to which piece of hardware?

Comment: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep_mode) about suspend mode. Your system will save data to RAM and it keeps minium power on it. So I guess when your PC goes below 5, your minium power which using for your RAM gone!

Comment: That's why they use water instead of icy for PC cooler.

Comment: @BeGood I am not sure if you are saying that some piece of my hardware is faulty or it's normal to expect such behaviour?

Comment: normal behaviour, but please don't let your PC too hot or too cold

Comment: Pay attention to condensation also! If the air is really dry that should not be a problem, but if it's humid, at 5°C you will probably start experiencing condensation effects (the inside of the PC is slightly warmer near CPU, RAM, power supply that are still working). You can have a look at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dew_point) if you want to exactly calculate the temperature and relative humidity to avoid condensation in your room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned that the my office often looses power over the night. I was not aware of it before, but figured I could ask to see if it's a hardware issue or not.

So I have no plugged the pc into the APC and I think this will not happen before.

Answer (score 1):

It is a hardware effect. You have a buildup of condensation on CPU socket, it short-cirquits near the power lines and the motherboard protection switches everything off.
*May be* your power unit or motherboard has a protection that shuts PC down when too cool to avoid condensation.
Anyway, you need a specially built PC to use in such conditions or at least a way to dry the air inside it.